# The characteristic polynomial of a rotation satisfies the relation $f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, isometry

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Greub, at page 237, it is asked to prove that

> The characteristic polynomial of a **proper** rotation satisfies the relation
>   $f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda^{-1})$

where a rotation defined as an isometry on a finite dimensional real inner product  space $E$.

I have tried the following:

$$(-\lambda)^n det(\phi - \lambda^{-1}i) = det(-\lambda \phi + i),$$

and we know that $det\phi = \pm 1$, so in a sense the above equation is similar to $\det(\phi - \lambda i)$, however the entries of the matrix of $\phi$ and $i$ are obviously different, and applying the definition of determinant given in the book, I couldn't arrive anywhere, so I would appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: $f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda -1)$ can't be right since the degrees in $\lambda$ don't match.  Perhaps you mean $f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda ^{-1})$?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, If you psace has dimension $n$, then the LHS has degree $n$, whereas the RHS has degree $2n$. Besides, I have Greub's textbok before my eyes and on page 273 there's nothing like that,

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have corrected the theorem, sorry for the type. PS: it is on page 237.

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, I was meant that, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as originally stated by our OP onurcanbektos can't be quite right, as is illustrated by the following example which is based upon the identiy map $I$ on $\Bbb R^3$:  consider $\phi = -I$ on $\Bbb R^3$:  the characteritic polynomial of $\phi$ is

$f(\lambda) = \det (-I - \lambda I) = \det((1 + \lambda)(-I)) = (1 + \lambda)^3 \det(-I) = -(1 + \lambda)^3; \tag 1$

then

$f(\lambda^{-1}) = -(1 + \lambda^{-1})^3, \tag 2$

and

$(-\lambda)^3 f(\lambda^{-1}) = -\lambda^3 (-(1 + \lambda^{-1})^3) = (1 + \lambda)^3; \tag 3$

here we have an example that

$f(\lambda) = -(-\lambda)^3 f(\lambda^{-1}); \tag 4$

now if our isometry is $I$, we find

$f(\lambda) = \det (I - \lambda I) = \det((1 - \lambda)I) = (1 - \lambda)^3 \det (I) = (1 - \lambda)^3, \tag 5$

and

$f(\lambda^{-1}) = (1 - \lambda^{-1})^3, \tag 6$

so that

$(-\lambda)^3f(\lambda^{-1}) = (-\lambda)^3 (1 - \lambda^{-1})^3 = -(\lambda(1 - \lambda^{-1}))^3$
$= -(\lambda - 1)^3 = (1 - \lambda)^3 = f(\lambda). \tag 7$

If we compare (4) and (7) we might speculate that there is a factor or other information related to $\det \phi$ which is missing from the equation as stated in the text of the question,

$f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda^{-1}); \tag 8$

in fact, I researched Greub's book, ***Linear Algebra***, and discovered that the actual problem quoted here, problem 9 on *p*. 237, reads

$"$9.)  Prove that the characteristic polynomial of a *proper* rotation satisfies

$f(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n f(\lambda^{-1})." \text{[italics mine.]} \tag 9$

Greub defines $\phi$ to be a *proper rotation* if it is an isometry with $\det \phi = 1$.

Based on this understanding, problem (9), *p*. 237 of Greub may be solved as follows:

$\phi$ is an isometry of the real inner product space $E$ if and only if it preserves inner products; that is, for $x, y \in E$ we have

$\langle \phi x, \phi y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle; \tag {10}$

this of course implies

$\langle x, \phi^T \phi y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle, \tag{11}$

and also

$\langle \phi^T \phi x, y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle; \tag{12}$

as is well-known, (11) and (12) imply

$\phi^T \phi = I = \phi \phi^T, \tag{13}$

which shows that $\phi$ is invertible and that

$\phi^{-1} = \phi^T; \tag{14}$

such transformations are also called *orthogonal*.  Since

$\det \phi^T = \det \phi, \tag{15}$

a well-known property of determinants, it follow from (13) that

$(\det \phi)^2 = (\det \phi^T)(\det \phi) = \det \phi^T \phi = \det I = 1; \tag{16}$

that is,

$\det \phi = \pm 1; \tag{17}$

we also have

$\det \phi^{-1} \det \phi = \det \phi^{-1} \phi = \det I = 1; \tag{18}$

combining this with (15) and (17) we find

$\det \phi^T = \det \phi^{-1} = \det \phi = \pm 1; \tag{19}$

if $\phi$ is *proper*, we choose the $+$ sign in (19).

With these preliminaries completed, we thus have:

$(\phi - \lambda I)^T = \phi^T - \lambda I, \tag{20}$

whence

$f(\lambda) = \det(\phi - \lambda I) = \det ((\phi - \lambda I)^T) = \det (\phi^T - \lambda I); \tag{21}$

then from (14),

$f(\lambda) = \det (\phi^T - \lambda I) = \det (\phi^{-1} - \lambda I)$
$= \det (\phi^{-1}(I - \lambda \phi)) = \det \phi^{-1} \det(I - \lambda \phi) =  \det(I - \lambda \phi), \tag{22}$

where we have exploited the $+1$ case of (19); we thus conclude:

$f(\lambda) = \det(I - \lambda  \phi) = \det (-\lambda I)\det(\phi - \lambda^{-1}I) = (-\lambda)^nf(\lambda^{-1}), \tag{23}$

establishing (8) for proper rotations.

In the event that $\phi$ is *not* a proper rotation, i.e., that $\det \phi = -1$, we can go back to (22) and pick up the derivation to find

$f(\lambda) = \det (\phi^T - \lambda I) = \det (\phi^{-1} - \lambda I)$
$= \det (\phi^{-1}(I - \lambda \phi)) = \det \phi^{-1} \det(I - \lambda \phi) =  -\det(I - \lambda \phi), \tag{24}$

from which it follows as in (23),

$f(\lambda) = -(-\lambda)^n f(\lambda^{-1}); \tag{25}$

we note these formulas are consisent with (4) and (8).

Comment: I have deleted my non-answer on reading this. Fancy including the non-rotations among the rotations!

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean I was not aware of that "proper" property even while trying to solve the problem myself.

Comment: @onurcanbektas:  well, it makes things a lot easier!  Cheers!